# conditional logging in dml for speed in production environments

Tags: dml-lang

I would like to optimize the dml-code I have for speed in a production environment. As far as I understand `log` statements such as:

```
log info, <n>: <string>;
```

Get translated in at least one if statement in the executable, because there is a need to check whether the `log-level` is larger than n.

I would like to avoid that by throwing the if statement out of the executable similar to `#define` and `#ifdef` statements in C and the only way I found in dml is by defining a constant and checking it and hoping the compiler will optimize out the code, recognizing it will never be executed.

```
constant LOG = 1; // there is not even the possibility to define a bool constant

if (LOG) log info, <n>: <string>;
```

My questions are:

- Is there a better (more efficient, more elegant) way to implement that?
- Will the dml-compiler or the C-compiler optimize the code out?
- How can I verify the code is no longer in the executable (or in the intermediate C source) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Note that trying to optimize away log statements (beyond the use of log levels/groups) is very likely premature, and only adds unneeded complexity to the model if so -- modeled devices only very rarely present a bottleneck within a simulation. Verify that the log statements actually do have a significant impact before resorting to trying to optimize them away.

That said, to answer each question in turn:

**1.**
Use the [compile-time if (else) statement](https://github.com/intel/device-modeling-language/wiki/3.-Device-Modeling-Language,-version-1.4#if-and-else-statements) (which is also available as an [object statement](https://github.com/intel/device-modeling-language/wiki/3.-Device-Modeling-Language,-version-1.4#conditional-objects)):

```
param do_log = true;
```

```
method m() {
    ....
    #if (do_log) log info, <n>: <string>;
}
```

Also note the use of [`param`](https://github.com/intel/device-modeling-language/wiki/3.-Device-Modeling-Language,-version-1.4#parameters) instead of [`constant`](https://github.com/intel/device-modeling-language/wiki/3.-Device-Modeling-Language,-version-1.4#constant-declarations) here. `param` is superior to `constant` in every way, with the only exception being that they can't be used within `typedef`s. As a plus, [parameter definitions can even be made through the DMLC flag `-D`](https://github.com/intel/device-modeling-language/wiki/2.-The-DML-compiler#command-line-options), which is useful for this kind of conditional compilation.

**2.**
The DML compiler typically doesn't eliminate any operations which aren't explicitly compile-time (like `#if` is). This is true for the run-time `if` statement: it won't get eliminated by DMLC no matter how simple the condition is.
However, as DMLC generates references to `constant`/`param` by simply replacing them by their definitions, the C compiler will receive a `if (1)` or `if (0)` and so will almost certainly optimize the branch away.

**3.**
As DMLC generates C, and generates that C with line directives to the original source file (unless `--noline` is provided to DMLC), you can look up the generated C corresponding to a given DML statement by searching for `#line [line of statement in DML source file] [path to DML source file]`. Although the generated C is certainly hard to read, for some simple statements like `if` the generated code can almost get verbatim to the original DML.

Answer (score 1):

My first reaction is that you should reconsider your ambition to do optimizations on this level. Do you have benchmarks that prove this code to be a bottleneck? The devices of a system seldom account for more than 5-10% of the total simulation time, and account for a vast majority of the development effort, so your device development effort is better spent on maintainability. There are definitely cases where devices account for more than that; in this case you need to understand why. It's often caused by a busy-wait loop, and there are techniques like hypersimulation that can be used to fast-forward simulation over busy-wait loops.

Also, the `if` generated by a `log` statement is an easy-to-predict branch instruction, so you will have a hard time even measuring the speed of it.

However, you may have other valid reasons for making sure a debug log is left out from the binary, e.g. concerns about code size or confidentiality. If you want to ensure that a statement stays outside the compiled result, then use `#if` instead of `if`. This ensures the body is expanded in compile-time; the discarded branch is even allowed to reference nonexistent identifiers.

To summarize, my answers to your three questions are:

- `#if` may be a better choice
- `#if` gives you a hard guarantee that the code will be optimized out by DMLC; if you use `if` then it will certainly be eliminated by the C compiler if you compile with optimization flags, but there is no formal guarantee.
- You can read the DML-generated code, `<host>/obj/modules/MODULE-NAME/DEVNAME-dml.c`.

And a final note: The recommended construct for constants in DML 1.4 is `param`; you can write `param LOG = true;`. `constant` is a remnant of DML 1.2, which remains only to bridge a current compiler limitation (`param`s cannot be used when specifying array sizes in `typedef`s).

Comment: There have been rare cases where a  device is polled and log code in the called-all-the-time register did contribute significantly to the Simics runtime.  I believe that was because somehow an expensive argument to log was computed before the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the other answer: you can use `#if` and a `param`. Like this:

```
// Not a complete device model
dml 1.4; 

param log_reg_bb_r50 = false;

// some bank
bank bb {

    register r50 size 8 @ 0x50 is write {
        method write(uint64 v) {
            default(v);
            log info, 1 : "Write to R50, standard log";
            #if(log_reg_bb_r50) {
                log info, 1 : "Write to R50, conditional log";
            }
        }
    }
}
```